# SQL Server TOP(1) with distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, dml

I am trying to extract the first row I get after ordering the result by `i_version_id`. If I do not use `TOP(2)`, my query works as expected ans returns all results sorted by i_version_id. But when I add the `TOP(2)` (as shown below), it says that there is a syntax error near `distinct`. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
SELECT TOP(2) 
    distinct(i_version_id) 
FROM 
    [PaymentGateway_2006].[dbo].[merchant] 
WHERE 
    dt_updated_datetime > '2013-11-11'
GROUP BY
    i_version_id 
ORDER BY 
    i_version_id;
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Distinct isn't necessary when you're already grouping by the same column you're selecting.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. I'm trying to figure out how you are going to possibly get different results with and without the distinct, and I think you're going to need to provide more info.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're only getting the `TOP 1` then `distinct` is irrelevant.  It's also irrelevant since grouping by the column will give you distinct values,

However, If you want more than one just remove the parentheses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP(2) 
    i_version_id
FROM 
    [PaymentGateway_2006].[dbo].[merchant] 
WHERE 
    dt_updated_datetime > '2013-11-11'
GROUP BY
    i_version_id 
ORDER BY 
    i_version_id;
```

Comment: Yea, but let's say I need 2 distinct top results.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
SELECT i_version_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i_version_id ASC) [counter]
FROM 
    [PaymentGateway_2006].[dbo].[merchant] 
WHERE 
    dt_updated_datetime > '2013-11-11'
GROUP BY
    i_version_id 
ORDER BY 
    i_version_id
) a
WHERE [counter] <= 2
```

This will give a row counter for each record.  Using GROUP BY and DISTINCT in your example above is pointless as your GROUP BY is already restricting your records.  Putting in the DISTINCT is just going to effect performance.

As for your error, you can't use TOP and DISTINCT together AFAIK.  You could try this if you wanted too:

```
SELECT
TOP 2 i_version_id
FROM
(
SELECT i_version_id 
FROM 
    [PaymentGateway_2006].[dbo].[merchant] 
WHERE 
    dt_updated_datetime > '2013-11-11'
GROUP BY
    i_version_id 
ORDER BY 
    i_version_id
) a
```

(I haven't tested this as I don't have your Db, but I can't see why this wouldn't do what you need).